# How to restrict user entering anything else other than email format

Tags: java, email, methods

I am trying to write a Java method that will check for the email format. The user should not be allowed to enter anything else in the field as mentioned below hardcoded email value. So the boolean method should return false value.

But somehow this doesn't seem to be working for me. In this case it is always returning true for me.
Can you please correct me where I am wrong? or can you please suggest me another solution?

```
public static boolean isValidEmailAddress(String email) {
    boolean result = true;
    email = "testemail@gmail.com" + "\'" + "\"" + "onmouseover=" + "\"" + "alert(20)" + "\"" + "\"";

    try {
        InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(email);
        emailAddr.validate();
    } catch (AddressException ex) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use Regex like this:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Email {

    private static final Pattern EMAIL_REGEX = Pattern.compile("^\\w+@\\w+(\\.\\w+){1,2}$");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isValidEmailAddress("testemail@gmail.com"));
        System.out.println(isValidEmailAddress("testemail@gmail.co.in"));
        System.out.println(isValidEmailAddress("testemail@gmail.co.in.blah"));
    }

    public static boolean isValidEmailAddress(String email) {
        return EMAIL_REGEX.matcher(email).matches();
    }    
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
true
true
false
```